# Global event listeners in wxPython

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wx.html2

I have a `wx.html2` widget in my `panel`. Sadly `wx.html2` doesn't have many event listeners (http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html2.WebView.html#events-events-emitted-by-this-class).

Now I have this binding to my `panel` (`self` is the `panel`);

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnRightClick)
```

.. and it works when I type in a blanco `panel/frame` as intended.

I wonder if there is a way to add more event listeners to the `wx.html2` manually or make a global event listener that listens, no matter the sub-widget the event happens in.

This does not work either (`self.wv` is the `wx.html` object);

```
self.wv.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnRightClick)
```

**Update**

I'm fixing the catching of keys/mouse-actions with JavaScript inside my HTML page now. It works, but I would like it more that actions can be bound to the `wx.html2` object.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few events emitted by WebView, all of which can be found in [WebView - wxPython (Phoenix) 2.9.5.80 documentation](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html2.WebView.html#events-events-emitted-by-this-class).